# why jquery form plugin conflict with fckeditor & file upload?

Tags: jquery, forms, plugins, fckeditor

I have created a form which contains the FCKEditor + File input box, and I am submitting the form using ajaxSubmit() method provided by jquery form plugin below.

> http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

If I don't use File input box, the FCKEditor values submit properly but if I add File input box in the form, the updated content of FCKEditor do not get stored. It stores old values only. Any suggestions ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it appears to be because the javascript function that attaches the handler to the file upload form is matching all forms in the page $('form') which includes the form that encapsulates the CKEditor.

You can solve this by adding an id field to your upload form and targeting that specific id when you attach the event handler so CKEditor is not affected.

e.g.

```
 <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_image_form">
    <input type="file" name="myfile"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload image to Server">
</form>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div >
    <div class="percent">0%</div >
</div>
<div id="status"></div>
$(document).ready(function() {
var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');
$('form#upload_image_form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
    status.empty();
     var percentVal = '0%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
        },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
     percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        status.html(xhr.responseText);
        percent.html('100%');
        bar.width('100%')
    }
});
});
```